# Why is Callback passed to RxJava map operator not being called?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java

UPD: I found a reason of this. I used String as a response type for `getPlayerHtml` request. Because of that it silently threw an Exception about malformed json etc. I needed to use `ResponseBody` from `okhttp3` and then convert it to string like `it.string()`.

I have the following function

```
    private fun getVideoFiles(video: Video): Single<Video> =
            api.getPlayerHtml(video.player).map {
                converter.parsePlaylists(it)
            }.map { converter.convertTracks(video, it) }
```

`api.getPlayerHtml` is a retrofit2 api method and it's actually the one that is called.

```
@GET
fun getPlayerHtml(@Url playerUrl: String) : Single<String>
```

After that I expect the response from it to be passed down to `converter.parsePlaylists` but it never happens since `converter.parsePlaylists` is not executed. Debugger doesn't even gets to the breakpoint that I've set there (inside of `converter.parsePlaylists`) for tests.

Can you please explain why it's working like that? I'm not an Android developer so I'm probably making some trivial mistakes here.

Comment: Can you show your code where you observe this Single?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm calling the function in a flatMap
`.flatMap { if (it.hosting is VideoHosting.VK) getVideoFiles(it) else Single.just(it) }`

Comment: I found a reason of this. I used String as a response type for `getPlayerHtml` request. Because of that it silently threw an Exception about malformed json etc. I needed to use `ResponseBody` from `okhttp3` and then convert it to string like `it.string()`.